# Is there a way to wait for an application to be created before continue in android testing?

Tags: android, robotium, android-testing

I'm also using [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) testing framework. My application does some setup work that is necessary to be done first in order for the tests to work.

I know that [ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2#getActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html#getActivity%28%29) is called, the activity is started if it hasn't already. But I need something setup first by the app or the code stops in error.

Answer (score 2):

When you are talking about pre-activity setup, are you doing it in you Application class.

It's not really clear, but if you have a Application class defined in your manifest, it will run before any activities.

However, if you do long-running stuff here it may block, and if you have threads you may have a race condition with your activity.

Comment: I don't have either. It's just database setup.

Comment: You can initialize your Database in you Application class. Create one, initialize in onCreate() and it'll be created before you use it. It's a good place to store a reference to your database as well since it's the most appropriate place for a global db connection.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is No. In android, testing is done before creating build

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. Robotium runs on the emulator, against the real application.

Answer (score 0):

You probably use

```
@Override public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}
```

prior to any tests. You should be able to insert your activity-setup-code there.